Why does Jason Portman look like 47 in the Isle of Sgàil but not at Haven?
In the Hitman (2016) level Situs Inversus, Jason Portman gets surgery to look like Helmut Kruger, who bears a resemblance to 47. We later see him on the Isle of Sgàil, showing that his surgery was a success, but then we see him again at Haven, and he looks nothing like 47.
What happened to his face?

Hey. Question seems fine, but could you please refrain from swearing in the future? Thanks.

The wiki only states: "His facial features do not resemble Helmut Kruger's, probably an indication that his extensive facial surgery was unsuccessful."
